# PHP 7.2 mysqli can not connect to MySQL with auth plugin sha256_password without SSL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7.2

Changing user auth plugin in MySQL to 'sha256_password':

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'N.N.N.N' IDENTIFIED WITH 'sha256_password' BY 'password';
```

`test.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$my = new mysqli('M.M.M.M', 'user', 'password');
echo "OK\n";
$my->close();
?>
```

Doesn't work with 'sha256_password':

```
php test.php
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'hostname' (using password: YES) in /home/user/test.php on line 3
```

Changing user auth plugin back to 'mysql_native_password':

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'N.N.N.N' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' BY 'password';
```

After changing auth plugin back to 'mysql_native_password' connection works:

```
php test.php
OK
```

Software versions:

```
php --version
PHP 7.2.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:41:59) ( NTS )

dpkg -l | grep libmysqlclient20
ii  libmysqlclient20:amd64                5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

mysqld -V
mysqld  Ver 5.7.26-29-57 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel29, Revision 03540a3, WSREP version 31.37, wsrep_31.37)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE** :

I also checked that it works with python MySQLdb connector:

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='user', passwd='password')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select 1')
print(cur.fetchall())
con.close()
```

Comment: Not sure the answer but the issue appears to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177511/how-do-you-connect-to-mysql-using-phps-mysqli-when-using-sha256-password-acces (`mysqli` needs to be instructred to use the `sha_256`.)

Comment: @user3783243 Do you know how to instruct mysqli to use sha_256? I can't find it in that question or in mysqli docs.

Comment: Although, in your case you see a message saying that MySQL couldn't log you in. This usually happens when you made a mistake in the username, password or didn't grant the privileges. If it was PHP fault you should see a message saying that the client can't recognize the authentication method

Comment: @Dharman I thought so, but the same php code works fine with the same user and password, if auth plugin is 'mysql_native_hashing'.

Comment: I actually don't know an answer to your question. I have found this useful links: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sha256-pluggable-authentication.html

Comment: @Dharman `#ifdef MYSQLND_HAVE_SSL` seems that it works only with SSL connections, while mysql client works with sha256_password without SSL as well.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2012/mysql-5-6-sha256-secure-password-support-for-php-mysqlnd/) how to use it. Unfortunately I don't have this mysqlnd plugin installed, so I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @SelivanovPavel Nope, but I've bountied the other question.

Comment: @Dharman I am using mysqlnd( phpinfo() says "mysqlnd => enabled" ), and native mysql client works fine with my sha256_password auth, but php doesn't.

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks, that's nice of you.

Comment: @SelivanovPavel Note that `#ifdef MYSQLND_HAVE_SSL` only checks whether mysqlnd has SSL support itself, not whether an SSL connection is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks that PHP 7.2.25(version from 21 Nov 2019) doesn't support MySQL 'sha256_password' authorization for connections without SSL.

Comment: Can you add the reference to where you found that?